# How can I compile C on Linux that will work on any distro?

Tags: c, linux, gcc

If I compile a self-contained project with gcc and statically link the C run-time library, will this work on any Linux distro? I don't care about any static link disadvantages (such as big file size) so long as it works. It is a closed-source project and this is beyond my control. The architecture of the PCs is the same.

Comment: What kind of project is it? I would recommend making it free software and package it for Debian .... static linking has several issues....

Comment: It close source project and this is beyond my control.

Comment: Then, be prepared to deal with several issues. static linking is for instance unfriendly with [nssswitch.conf(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/nsswitch.conf.5.html) -used a lot in networking applications- and [dlopen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html)

Comment: Can you tell us what you (or your employer) are trying to achieve? Even for closed source projects, the C runtime isn't traditionally statically linked.

Comment: The library contains only some "maths" functions, there is no network access, disk io, or anything else. It contains proprietary algorithms.

Comment: It's an issue of underlying hardware whether it's x86,x86_64,arm or anything else, it's not a matter of distro.if you compile for x86_64 it will only run on x86 not on arm, or even x86.

Comment: @rakib Thanks. We have the same arch on PCs that's not a problem.

Answer (score 2):

If you can guarantee that all of the code it will execute is self-contained in the binary you ship, then theoretically (emphasis on theoretically) it should work on any linux distribution.  In this process there are an enormous number of pitfalls. My personal opinion is that it is pretty much impossible to make this work due to changing interfaces across versions. Interfacing with other libraries is a fragile nightmare.

Most companies that I'm familiar with (including my own) produce builds made for different distributions. There are some complications that result from having to make a build for SLES, Redhat, etc., but I'm confident that providing a few different builds ultimately is simpler and causes less problems than attempting to statically link everything.

Comment: The library contains only 2 simple functions, they will never change and if they do I can just recompile it.

Comment: Perhaps your case is an exception then if its that simple.

Comment: I once had to use some "maths" functions as you say on an embedded device and we actually included a implementation of them in our source code. We did this for size, not for portability, but if it really is that simple you probably can do it.

Comment: You must follow book beginning Linux programming in which it is clearly mention that how we can create static library or connect with static library. By default our Linux use dynamic library.